# Json object not fetching properly in IE11

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I am making an axios call to fetch a JSON object which works fine in Chrome and other browsers but in IE11 when i console the data key inside the object its fetching string that too half, so I am not able to convert it into JSON also from JSON.parse.

```
   axios.get("/bin/users")
      .then(response => {
          console.log('response',response);
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      })
```

This is the call i am making. Inside response we have a data key which is actually an object. but its breaking into string that too in between in IE11 due to which when i am trying to access same data key in IE11 its throwing undefined error because am not able to access that key since it got converted to broken string and using JSON.parse also throws error because string is cut from in between in IE11

Comment: I try to make some research about this issue and found that in some old threads the issue was fixed by adding the [promise-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill). I suggest you try to make a test with this polyfill that may help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add `Accept: 'application/json'` and `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` headers and the problem was fixed.